# Can a Slackbot create emoji?

Tags: slack, emoji, bot

The only emoji command I can find is `https://api.slack.com/methods/emoji.list`

Is there a way to programatically create custom emoji? Or is the only way via manual process - https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/206870177-Creating-custom-emoji

Comment: I know this is an old question but I was wondering if you found a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @Carl have not found a way to do it yet. Looks to be manual still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on enterprise grid, you can use the recently added `admin.emoji.add` https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.emoji.add

Answer (score 9):

There's an [undocumented](https://github.com/slackhq/slack-api-docs/issues/94) API endpoint for this: [`emoji.add`](https://github.com/slackhq/slack-api-docs/issues/28#issuecomment-424195796) (and its little buddy `emoji.remove`).

### `emoji.add` POST parameters

- token (either in POST body or `Authorization: Bearer` header) (There's an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/slackhq/slack-api-docs/issues/95) that claims you can't use `xoxb` tokens, [only `xoxs` ones](https://github.com/jackellenberger/emojme#finding-a-slack-token).)
- mode (`data`)
- name (what you want as the custom emoji's name, e.g. `my-party-parrot`)
- image (the file)

### `emoji.remove` POST parameters

- token (either in POST body or `Authorization: Bearer` header)
- name (which custom emoji you want to remove, e.g. `my-party-parrot`)

Here's what it looks like in Postman:

[image: Postman - Slack API - emoji.add]

In CURL, the call would look like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://slack.com/api/emoji.add \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [REDACTED] \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' \
  -F mode=data \
  -F name=my-party-parrot \
  -F image=@/home/curtis/Downloads/some-file.jpg
```

Everything that I know about this comes from from [Jack Ellenberger's ":slack_on_fire:" article](https://medium.com/@jack.a.ellenberger/slack-on-fire-part-two-please-stop-rotating-my-user-token-replay-attacking-slack-for-emoji-fun-c87da4e54b03) and his [emojme](https://github.com/jackellenberger/emojme/blob/e076b58bbe310da154013b51f77d3e1047938983/lib/emoji-add.js#L79-L82) library.

Comment: This approach can not be used with normal tokens (user, bot, legacy) and only works with internal xoxs tokens, which you have to grab manually from the browser. Its also unclear how long they live. So this is a hack and I personally would not use this with any production app for Slack.

Answer (score 1):

Slack's official web API does not support the programmatic creation of emojis.

Comment: thanks for answering. Source on that?

Comment: Here is the list of all web API methods. There is no method for that function. https://api.slack.com/methods